# Why does QModelIndex internalid is 0?

Tags: c++, qt

I have subclassed the `QAbstractTableModel` and I populate it with data. Then I am trying to use the `QModelIndex` internal ID of each element, but for some reason it's always 0:

```
const QModelIndex ind = m_varTabModel.index(row, col);
qDebug() << "Internal ID:" << ind.internalId();
```

The `m_varTabModel` is an object of the type that subclasses the `QAbstractTableModel` and `row` + `col` are valid row and column numbers.

Is the internal ID set only in some specific situations?

Comment: I guess the internal ID value is set by specific models and implementation dependent. See `QAbstractItemModel::createIndex(int row, int column, quint32 id)` function.

Comment: So In order to set specific ID's for each model index, I would have to subclass the `QAbstractItemModel` as well?

Comment: `internalId` is often used with a custom model to get a pointer/index on the data. See [this example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-simpletreemodel-example.html) for more info

Comment: @Bremen, No. If you subclass a model, in its `index()` function you should call `QAbstractItemModel::createIndex()` function overload and set an ID for each model index it creates and returns.

Comment: What I need is simply to be able identify each element ever entered to the table by an unique ID. If I will create a new index each time I can `index` this wont do I think. Is subclassing `QAbstractItemModel` necesarry in here?

Comment: @Bremen, why cannot you uniquely identify each element by its `QModelIndex`? I don't think you need another identifier, unless you have solid reason for it.

Comment: Well, I need a specific key for the QHash

Comment: Now when I think of it, maybe the `QModelIndex` could be my key as wel...

Comment: Ok, This wont work. As soon as a row is deleted, the `QModelIndex` changes...

Comment: This is beginning to sound a bit XY.  What's the underlying problem you're trying to solve?  Can you describe what your model is supposed to represent?

Comment: Ok. I have a full path to a file. But in the model, I only save the file name. This means the full path is lost. I need to be able to restore it somehow. I thought I could use QModelIndez for that.